# How to Fix Network Sharing after Windows 8.1 Upgrade?

Tags: windows, networking

I had previously been using a Windows 8.0 Desktop successfully to share files across my home network. I had Home Sharing enabled. I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and it broke. No matter what I do, I get the following error when trying to connect to the network drive:

"The network folder specified is currently mapped using a difference name and password. To connect using a different user name and password, first disconnect any existing mappings to this network share."

I have tried everything. In the command line I have deleted the share:

```
net use /delete "\\server\my share"
```

I confirmed that "my share" is now gone and there are no other shares on the server. I am trying to connect from a Windows 7 Enterprise PC. This has worked for years...now broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely appears in context where your PC has some form of shared resource open on the computer you are trying to connect to. The message means the authentication is OK, however by design windows is preventing two different accounts connecting to the same server from one computer (your PC). Even after you delete the connection, my experience has been the information persists in caches for some time.

You can read more about this here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938120

In the most straightforward case you would make sure there are no automatically mapping drives (persisting across reboot), then shut down your computer. After reboot you should be able to map drives. If not - maybe then there is a service running in another user's name from your computer that is connecting something on startup.

Comment: That was it. Using manual IP address fixed it. Thanks r0berts! Will vote you up when I get my score up :)

Comment: Nice to know it helped, cheers :)